# Azure pipelines yaml permission denied

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy using azure pipelines.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
```

I think its becuase the node_modules folder is not being shared between stages. But I cant figure out what is proper way to do it.

Here is my yaml file:

```
variables:
  - group: netlify

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages: 
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: ARM
        steps:
        - task: NodeTool@0
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '10.x'
          displayName: 'Install Node.js'

        - script: |
            npm install
            npm run unit
          displayName: 'Setup and test'

        - script: npm run build
        - publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
          artifact: dist
  - stage: Deploy
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - job: APP
        steps:
        - bash: |
           npm i -g netlify-cli
           netlify deploy --site $(NETLIFY_SITE_ID) --auth $(NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN) --prod
```

After running npm install, package node_modules should appear somehwere in the directory but it seems its not properly shared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `Ubuntu` image, and trying to global install `netlify-cli` in **Linux without `sudo`**.

If the `Ubuntu` is the necessary system you must use, you'd better add `sudo` before this command:

```
sudo npm i -g netlify-cli
```

[Command succeed on my pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5SRx.jpg)

In this doc, [Upgrading on *nix (OSX, Linux, etc.)](https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm#upgrading-on-nix-osx-linux-etc):

> You may need to prefix these commands with sudo, especially on Linux,
>   or OS X if you installed Node using its default installer.

Same in [VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#install-tools-on-your-build-agent), you must use `sudo` in the command to let you has password-less sudo rights for `Ubuntu`.

[image]

---

Another way is change the image to `vs2017-win2016` if you do not has any special requirements for the build environment:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
```

When using this image, you could install anything and do not need use `sudo`.

---

In fact, we has been pre-installed many basic tools in all hosted images, including `node.js`

In our [github description](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation#image-contents), we listed all tools that pre-installed for all images. You can check to know more about VSTS.

Comment: `Deploy path:        /home/vsts/work/1/s/dist
Configuration path: /home/vsts/work/1/s/netlify.toml
No such directory /home/vsts/work/1/s/dist! Did you forget to create a functions folder or run a build?
`

Comment: @AlexT Which task this error occurred? According this error, the task is finding **dist** from your **s** (For VSTS, **s** means **source directory**) But, if I’m not misunderstand, **dist** should just be your artifact name, right? If this, this error is correct. But did not see you specify this path in your deploy stage, could you let me know more about details?

Comment: Weel I think when running `npm install` and `npm build` I should get those `node_modules` and `dist` folders in the directory Im currently in. And then the next command is looking for those folders in the file it is currently in. However im not sure how artifacts should work in this case. Could you help me out with this?

Comment: @AlexT, Do you want `node_modules` and `dist` was access by who? The next stage? If this, you should pack and publish them together. In next stage, if you want this artifact can be use, please download them(there has a `download artifact task`). Only this, the artifact can be available for next stage. If above is not what you want, don't hesitate to correct me.

Comment: Yes the steps in next stage should be able to access `dist` and `node_modules`. So you mean i should do only one stage?

Comment: @AlexT, You can but not recommend. Put them together would let you avoid those path error. But as normal, deploy should be in one separate stage. Limited by comment, you can refer to the YAML in this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617482/dependent-job-getting-value-from-a-previous-stage

Comment: @AlexT, the issue reported in that ticket has been fixed by us. So you can directly that op's YAML which showed in his question.

Comment: @AlexT, Just want to confirm is there any assistance I can give to you on this puzzle? Don't hesitate to let me know if you need.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into that post and changed this in my deploy stage: `jobs:
      - job: APP
        steps:
        - download: current
          artifact: dist
        - bash: |
           sudo npm i -g netlify-cli
           netlify deploy --site $(NETLIFY_SITE_ID) --auth $(NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN) --prod`, however it seems it does not pickup the artifact still.

Comment: Somehow in the first step it downloads to folder: `/home/vsts/work/1/dist` but in next steps it looks inside `/home/vsts/work/1/s/dist!` folder, not sure why

Comment: @AlexT, you are using YAML which combine the build and release both in Build pipeline, its limitation is all of them compile logic is following Build especially **build directory**. This means even it is a release pipeline, its work space and work directory still be `s`. For classic UI of release, it is `a`. That's why here it is picking something from `s`. I think here, you'd better specify the file location in your `netlify deploy` script by following this doc: https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#deploy-directories. I am not very familiar with this netlify, hope it could help.

Comment: So it is not possible to change the directory where the artifact is downloaded to?

Comment: @AlexT. No, it can, just you could not use current download format any more. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet. These 2 tasks can all let you change the destination directory. Suggest you raise a new ticket for this puzzle you are facing, thus I and other community members can together share our suggestion to you. You know, comment has words limitation.

Comment: Sure I will do that